# DMI issue with struts 2.3.29 in tomcat

Tags: java, struts2

My web app uses struts 2.3.15 and deployed in tomcat 7.0.47 (and in tomcat 8.0.15 too). I have used most of the calls using DMI (Dynamic Method Invocation) using urls like `/testapp/userspace/user!getRole.action`

Now I have updated the application to struts version 2.3.29 and any of the DMI methods are not working and return 404 error.

I do understand that struts has made default configuration for DMI to false (struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation) after version 2.3.xx (where xx above 15) but using struts configuration file I made that enabled, still its not working. I checked using config-browser plugin and seems its not getting enabled, although I have made the configuration to enable it.

My struts-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

</struts>
```

web.xml

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>struts-default.xml,
                struts-plugin.xml,
                /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.isa.maxaero.web.action</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

I have also learned that this issue is not with jboss server since we have done the same change to another app that runs on jboss and it works as expected.

Any suggestions on how to made `struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation` to **true**.

Comment: Read release notes before upgrading - http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-StrictDMI.

Comment: I have read the release note and it do not contain anything related on this. What I want to do is make DMI available, not making method invocation strict. Anyway I have found the solution partially right now and update on this once it completed.